# selecting column output into a string. Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am looking for a way to customize my output in hive.

For example my query is.

```
select col1,col2 from table1
```

I want `col1` and `col2` to be inserted in a predefined string like.

"Hey there, value1 is `<col1>` and value2 is `<col2>`"

And if possible all of this goes into an output file on local filesystem. Please suggest a way for doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
hive -e 'select concat('Hey there value1 is ', col1, ' and value2 is ', col2, '.') as my_string from my_table' > /path/localfilesystem/filename.txt
```